# Using XPath to get child elements

Tags: java, xpath

I'm trying to use DocumentBuilder and XPath to parse an XML document with structure like:

```
<questionnaire>
  <item>
    <question>How have you been?</question>
    <response>Great</response>
    <response>Good</response>
    <response>So-so</response>
    <response>Bad</response>
    <response>Rather not answer</response>
  </item>
</questionnaire>
```

To access question I've done this (which works):

```
expression = "/questionnaire/item[" + i + "]/question";
setQuestion(xmlReader.read(expression, XPathConstants.STRING).toString());
```

Now I need some way to create a list of string based on the response items. The number of responses is variable so one question could have any number of responses. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm no pro at this, but if you have multiple items, wouldn't you do better to parse the XML with DOM or JAXB to be able to better get the question and the associated responses?

Comment: I spoke with a few of the Java developers at work. One suggested that I change my responses structure to <responses><response>..</response></responses> so it'd make it easier with any of the various systems I go with. The two methods that came up as being the best solutions would be Xstream and JAXB. I'm not sure if that'll help anyone searching along the lines of this topic but I felt I'd share what info on this topic I could.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this won't do it? You have to note that xmlReader.read probably return a collection in that case.

```
expression = "/questionnaire/item[" + i + "]/response";
setResponse(xmlReader.read(expression, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

Comment: I tried that initially and at best I get a List<Response> with only the first element filled.